# Два "уровня" фреймворков

Tags: веб-программирование, архитектура, фреймворк

Есть фреймворки которые слабо влияют на архитектуру программы в целом, они влияют только на отдельные ее части - например контейнеры IoC с DI. Ведь такие фреймворки по сути не заставляют программиста строить приложение определенным образом. Они заставляют определенным образом создавать классы, но общую структуру они не задают.

А есть фреймворки (Yii) которые задают структуру на другом уровне, они предоставляют возможности для реализации определенных частей приложения, например  модулей, компонентов, виджетов. Т.е. это более высокий уровень организации.

Вопрос (достаточно размытый): является ли два перечисленных "типа" фреймворков, фреймворками? Структуру какого уровня должен задавать фреймворк?

P.S. Никогда не пользовался фреймворками, в связи с чем не могу судить по своему опыту

Comment: Фреймворк - это дословно каркас. А каркасом в принципе можно назвать что угодно. Нет здесь никакой чёткой классификации. Чаще всего фреймворками официально называют наборы инструментов/библиотек, которые изначально задуманы быть каркасом, но это не правило. Вы можете собрать какие угодно библиотеки в кучу и назвать это всё личным фреймворком.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf спасибо